# Deinterlace H.265 with gstreamer

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to stream an H.265-compressed video from an embedded platform. The video is acquired by an analog camera whose output is interlaced, then compressed by an hw encoder.

If I use no compression and acquire a file using v4l2-ctl, deinterlacing on my PC using ffplay, things are perfect:

```
# On the embedded system 
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -w --verbose --set-fmt-video=width=720,height=288,pixelformat=YUYV --stream-mmap --stream-count=300 --stream-to=test.raw
# Deinterlacing on my PC
ffplay -s 768x288 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i test.raw -vf tinterlace=mode=0
```

However, when using gstreamer, the video I acquire does not work anymore. I have tried fitting the *deintelace* plugin everywhere in the pipeline, I've tried with and without H.265 compression, I've tried with and without UDP streaming, ... it simply "ignores" the deinterlacer.

The pipeline below (on the trasmitter side) is what I have so far:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw,width=720,height=288,format=YUY2,interlaced=true ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! deinterlace ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw, format=YUY2" ! nvvidconv ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420 interlaced=false" ! nvv4l2h265enc ! rtph265pay ! udpsink port=$PORT host=$HOST_IP
```

On the receiver side I use:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=$PORT ! "application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H265, payload=96" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Any suggestion to get the same effect as v4l2-ctl/ffplay but using gstreamer ?

Comment: Did you check with GStreeamer 1.18.1? I believe in that changelog there was a hint for h265parse and interlace mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I haven't, but with further investigations it seems that deinterlace does not do its job at all even on pure raw videos... I've posted a message on the Gstreamer-devel ML...

Comment: Apparently is a bug in the pipeline, the deinterlacing I need is not supported before 1.18+... Thanks anyway!!